# vimscript templating with global-counter

Tags: markdown, vim

I am trying to create a generic markdown template, using a vimscript.
Each time the template is called, I would like to increment a counter.

**function 1**

`#CNTR=` is read/parsed from the markdown file, incremented

```
function! GetCNTR()
    let yogaf = readfile("yoga.js")
```

I read from `last-line - 1`.  `last` (the line number) prints.  However, `item` (the value at
list index) does not:

```
    let last=len(yogaf)-1
    let item= yogaf[last]
        echo item
        let indx = 0
```

I'm a little confused by the vimscript pattern for looping through a list.  I tried several things, including `#CNTR=*`... but no luck with finding a match!

```
    for i in yogaf
        if i =~ "#CNTR=\&"
            let indx = i
            break
        else
            let indx = len(yogaf)-1
        endif
    endfor
```

When the function is called, I don't see `indx`, `cnt`, or `CNTR` printed.

```
    echo indx
    let cnt = yogaf[indx]
    echo string(cnt)
    let [g:CNTR] = cnt[6:]
    echo g:CNTR
    return g:CNTR
endfunction
```

**function2**

calls *function1*, gets `g:CNTR`, then writes template to markdown file

**function3**

increments `g:CNTR` and writes update to file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your trying to do but some of things you do in this script don't make sense (mainly the for loop).

I'm going to try and explain what I think your doing and what you should be doing

```
let yogaf = readfile("yoga.js")
```

This reads in the file as a list of strings into yagaf. (This is fine)

```
let last=len(yogaf)-1
let item= yogaf[last]
```

This gets the last line. However this can be simplified to just using a negative index which index from the end of the list. However this whole line is useless and does nothing cause all you do is print item

```
let item = yogaf[-1]
```

Next you have a for loop where you iterate over the lines in and try and find a line that matches the pattern `#CNTR=\&` if you find it you store it in index. If you don't find it you store the last line number in index.

```
for i in yogaf
    if i =~ '#CNTR=\&'
        let indx = i
        break
    else
        let indx = len(yogaf)-1
    endif
endfor
```

At the end of this for loop indx is either a string containing the line that matches or the number of lines in the file. I really doubt this is what you meant to do.

I think what you meant to do is find the line that matched `#CNTR=` so thats what I'm going to change it to do.

You can match that with the line `i =~# '#CNTR='` This will match any line that contains `#CNTR=` in it (and has the same case). Your other regex `#CNTR=*` means match any line with `#CNTR=*` with zero or more = equal signs. Which might match but you probably wanted anything after the equal sign which would have been `#CNTR=.*` (`.` matches anything `*` zero or more times)

After the for loop you had

```
echo indx
let cnt = yogaf[indx]
echo string(cnt)
let [g:CNTR] = cnt[6:]
echo g:CNTR
return g:CNTR
```

cnt will (almost) never be what you want you could get lucky but if your string matched (which it probably did) you would be indexing the list with a string and vim seems to return the first line which probably isn't what you want.

for the line `cnt[6:]` I think you are trying to strip `#CNTR` from the front of the string you matched. However cnt doesn't contain what you want.

So lets just modify the for loop to set `g:CNTR` to the correct value and return if a matching line is found.

```
for i in g:yogaf
    if i =~ '#CNTR='
        let g:CNTR = i[6:]
        return g:CNTR
    endif
endfor
```

At the end of this loop `g:CNTR` will either be set or you didn't find anything. If you didn't find anything I set `g:CNTR` equal to -1 and return that.

```
let g:CNTR = -1
return g:CNTR
```

So the completed function should look something like this (with all extraneous stuff removed)

```
function! GetCNTR()
    let l:yogaf = readfile("yoga.js")
    for i in l:yogaf
        if i =~ '^#CNTR='
            let g:CNTR = i[6:]
            return g:CNTR
        endif
    endfor
    let g:CNTR = -1
    return g:CNTR
endfunction
```

Although I'm not even sure this is what you want because you didn't actually ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

For templates consider using a plugin like [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) (if your vim is built with Python support) or [snipmate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540).

Ultisnips allows you to use Python in snippets. Both allow you to use vimscript in the snippets.

Comment: thanks! i prefer python for quick scripting, so this looks interesting.